# Split string after second occurence of any digit?

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to split a string (if possible with a newline) after every second occurence of any digit. Or in other words: replace every space after the second digit with a newline. Or putting them in a list would work too.

```
a = "4 one 3 5 two two 6 6 three 14 7 four four four 7"
"\n".join(a.split("\d", 2)[:2])
```

Should return

```
"4 one 3"
"5 two two 6"
"6 three 14"
"7 four four four 7"
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about this task? What happened when you tried to do this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm not even coming close to a solution. I tried stuff like: `"\n".join(a.split("\d", 2)[:2])`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Nop, trying to split up a scraped box-score.

Comment: `(\d+.*?\d+)` <- this regex (nongreedy "number + anything + number") should match the items groupped as you want it, so get them all the regex's groups

Comment: What should be the result for `a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with a space and look-ahead and look-behind assertions for digits:

```
import re

re.split(r"(?<=\d) (?=\d)", a)
# ['4 one 3', '5 two two 6', '6 three 14', '7 four four four 7']
```

Comment: What does the ```?=``` refer to?

Comment: That's called a positive lookahead. It means whatever we're matching (the single space here) must be directly followed by a digit (`\d`), but without the digit being part of the match itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = "4 one 3 5 two two 6 6 three 14 7 four four four 7"
indices = [x.start() for x in re.finditer('\d+', a)] #Find out all indices where digit 0 to 9 is occurred.
result = []
for i in range(0, len(indices),2):   # i traverses through all indices
    result.append(a[indices[i]:indices[i+1]+1]) # String slicing is
for s in result:
    print(s)
```

String slicing is done from odd occurrence of digit[0-9] to even occurrence of digit[0-9] and it is appended in a list.

### Output

4 one 3

5 two two 6

6 three 14

7 four four four 7

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = "4 one 3 5 two two 6 6 three 14 7 four four four 7"
result = re.split(r"(?<=\d) (?=\d)", a)
for s in result:
    print(s)
```

## Output

4 one 3

5 two two 6

6 three 14

7 four four four 7